# アンダースコアを代入する( var a:Int = _ )の意味(定義)は？

Tags: scala

あるコードで

```
var a:Int = _
```

という感じのものを見たのですが、どういう意味(定義)なんでしょうか？
実際には 0 がはいるみたいですが。

Comment: 0を入れない意味・意義的なのを知りたいです。実際に0として使えてしまうみたいなのですが

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[言語仕様のVariable Declarations and Definitions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variable-declarations-and-definitions)によれば、型によって

- Int -- 0
- Long -- 0L
- Float -- 0.0f
- Double -- 0.0d
- Boolean -- false
- Unit -- ()
- 他の型 -- null

がそれぞれ代入されます。

動作は 0 などを代入した場合と同じです。

次のコードをコンパイルして

```
class A1 {
  var i: Int = _
  var l: Long = _
  var f: Float = _
  var d: Double = _
  var b: Boolean = _
  var u: Unit = _
  var o: AnyRef = _
}

class A2 {
  var i: Int = 0
  var l: Long = 0L
  var f: Float = 0.0f
  var d: Double = 0.0d
  var b: Boolean = false
  var u: Unit = ()
  var o: AnyRef = null
}
```

javap -c でコンストラクタみてみると A1 は

```
public A1();
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: invokespecial #63                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
     4: return
```

と代入が行われていないのに対し、A2 は

```
public A2();
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: invokespecial #63                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
     4: aload_0
     5: iconst_0
     6: putfield      #25                 // Field i:I
     9: aload_0
    10: lconst_0
    11: putfield      #33                 // Field l:J
    // 以下代入が続く
```

というように代入が行われます。

バイトコード上は代入が行われず、[Java言語仕様の初期値](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#4.12.5) がそのまま利用されるようです。

Answer (score 0):

初期値(デフォルト値)が入ります。Intなら0ですがStringならnull, Booleanならfalseです。

```
var a:Int = _
a: Int = 0

var a:String = _
a: String = null

var a:Boolean = _
a: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 0):

`_` によって初期値を表し、その変数が未定義であることを防ぐことができます。

[参考](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1203/02/news118.html)

Comment: "Scala は型推論言語なので、実行時に初めて初期値が決定され" のあたりが、この場合型推論関係ない気がします

Comment: @KenjiYoshida  確かにそうですね、コメントを修正しておきました。